# Does an .obj file exported from Blender contain a texture?

Tags: texturing, objects, export

I searched online for the question about whether an *.obj* file contains a   texture. Some people said that we can extract textures from the *.obj* file, some said that the *.obj* file only stores geometry data and does not keep any materials and textures. Some online tutorials said "*Export the model together with the texture into the obj file*". When I study the example from three.js, the script takes the texture file and the *obj* file separately. So, it is so confusing as to whether the *.obj* file exported from Blender contains a texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export an obj from blender, it creates a .obj and a .mtl file.  As I understand it, the .obj file contains the geometry data and the .mtl file contains the texture data.  So as long as you keep the .obj file, the .mtl file, and the textures together, your model should retain its texture.

Comment: For some examples, I see there are also `.dds` files. When I delete it, the texture is gone. However, there is no `.dss` files generated after export. So, it is necessary to have `.dds` files for the rendering?

Comment: @CasperLIWaiKin  a .dds file is a Microsoft format for storing data compressed with the proprietary S3 Texture Compression (S3TC) algorithm, so it is possible that image is your texture.  If that is the case than yes, you would need to keep it.

Comment: Can Blender generate `.dds` file?

Comment: I don't think so.